# Zero momentum of photons

Tags: special-relativity, photons

Using the energy–momentum relation,
$$E^2=(pc)^2+\left(m_0c^2\right)^2,$$
we arrive at
$$E=pc$$
if a particle is massless ($m_0=0$). But, since
$$p=m_{0}\gamma v,$$
the momentum of a photon would be zero as well as its energy.

Doesn't this contradict $E=hf$?

Comment: Obviously, $p=E/c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Massless particles move with $v=c$ and thus have $\gamma=\infty$. So that $p=m_0\gamma v$ isn’t useful for massless particles because the right-hand side is zero times infinity, which is indeterminate rather than zero.