# Different results for energy of photon when using expression for kinetic energy and Planck's relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, particle-physics, photoelectric-effect

1. Using Planck's relation between
   frequency and energy of a photon.
   $E=hf$

   $f=(v/\lambda)$, but $v$=c for light, thus

   $f=c/\lambda$ , substituting this expression for $f$ in Planck's relation:

   $E=hc/\lambda$....1

   Now using De Brogile's relation:

   $\lambda=h/p$ , where p is the
   momentum of the photon,
   substituting this relation for
   $\lambda$ in 1

   $E=hc \times p/h = pc$

   2.Now using the expression for
   kinetic energy We get:

   $E=1/2(mv^2)$

   But $v=c$ and $mv=mc=p$,
   Since momentum=mass times
   velocity

   Thus

   $E=pc/2$

This is half the energy derived using Planck's relation but why?

also, unless $p$ varies with $f$ (which it does according to De-Brogile's relation) photons of various frequencies would have the same energy, but this is false as Planck's relation states $E=hv$ but for $p$ to be a variable the mass of a photon must be variable since $p=mc$ and c is a constant.

Please explain this.

Comment: Think about why the use of $p=mc$ or $E=1/2\, mv^2$ is problematic in the case of photons. Hint: What is the mass of a photon?

Comment: @Jakob is the mass of a photon undefined? So I need a way of expressing momentum with no reference to mass?

Comment: No, it is zero, cf. [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/521431/zero-momentum-of-photons). Yes, the equation $p=mv$ does not apply for photons. I guess there are a lot of similar questions here on SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photons follow Lorentz transformations and are described by [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) whose invariant mass is zero.

[image: invmass]

This is the mathematically correct derivation of the energy of the photon with respect to its momentum, setting $m_0$ to zero, $E=pc$ ,thus 1) is the correct expression.

The photon has mass zero, and what you call its kinetic energy  becomes zero. The formula of kinetic energy for massive particles' cannot apply for zero mass particles. They just have energy and momentum.

Comment: Gee! Thanks a lot. that's a lot to swallow though.